# What's the name for a distribution of the form $10^D$, where $D$ is a known distribution?

Tags: distributions, terminology, uniform-distribution, distribution-identification

In my particular case, I'm generating uniformly random numbers and using them as the power to a base-10 exponent, e.g. in R:

```r
s <- 10^runif(10, 1, 10)
```

Is there a name for this distribution, i.e., $s \sim 10^{\mathcal{U}(1,10)}$?

Sorry if this is poorly worded, if you understand what I'm asking you can feel free to edit this post to clarify it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $10^D = \exp(kD)$  (where $k=\ln(10)$); your uniform on (1,10) is still uniform when you multiply it by $k$, so (by analogy with distributions like the log-normal, whose log is normal and the log-logistic, whose log is logistic), we *might* call it log-uniform.

And indeed, when $D$ is normal, $10^D$ is log-normal, so this fits quite well.

[However, that usage isn't always consistent across distributions.]

Answer (score 3):

I do not think it has a name, but it loosely resembles [Exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) with $\lambda = 1$ and uniformly distributed $x$'s. Notice however that you get something strange of it, since as [Uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29) is

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{b - a} & \mathrm{for}\ a \le x \le b, \\
0 & \mathrm{for}\ x<a\ \mathrm{or}\ x>b
\end{cases} 
$$

then if $U \sim \mathcal{U}(a, b)$ and $s = 10^U$, you get

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
10^{\frac{1}{b - a}} & \mathrm{for}\ a \le x \le b, \\
1 & \mathrm{for}\ x<a\ \mathrm{or}\ x>b
\end{cases} 
$$

and I am not sure if this is what you were thinking of...

Comment: Interesting point. I guess I would want the bottom piece to remain 0?

Comment: That is why I said that your definition is probably not what you meant by it...